# Cannot move UILabel position programatically

Tags: ios, swift

I have a file for the View section of app, where i have all the labels and images that i intent to use, this is what i have in my `DetailViewTableCell` class, which inherits from `UIView`.

```
class DetailViewTableCell: UIView {

    
    var detailMainImage: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var detailName: UILabel = UILabel()
    var detailType: UILabel = UILabel()
    var detailHeart: UIImageView = UIImageView()
}
```

Now i move to my `DetailViewController` class, here i try and add the label, the label is added but it appears always at top left corner at 0,0 coordinate, when i try and add constraints for position, i always get error, now i can try

```
detailMain.detailName.frame.origin.x = 30
```

but i get error:

> Constraint items must each be a view or layout guide.

In any case i do not wish to use this approach but more something like this

```
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: detailMain.detailName, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: detailMain.detailName.superview, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

but i get the same above error, my over all code is this:

```
self.view.addSubview(detailMain.detailName)
        detailMain.detailName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        detailMain.detailName.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
        detailMain.detailName.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        detailMain.detailName.font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 30)
        detailMain.detailName.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        detailMain.detailName.textColor = UIColor.black
```

Which works perfectly fine but the moment i try and constraints, the error come up, this is how the app shows up with out constraints and name at top most left corner

[image]

////////UPDATE

So here is my new `DetailViewTableCell`,

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewTableCell: UIView {
    

    
    var detailMainImage: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    
    var detailName: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    var detailType: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    var detailHeart: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        [detailMainImage, detailName, detailType, detailHeart].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview($0)
        }
        
       NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                 
                 // constrain main image to all 4 sides
                 detailMainImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                 detailMainImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                 detailMainImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
                 detailMainImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
                 
                 // activate the height contraint
                
                 
                 // constrain detailType label
                 //  30-pts from Leading
                 //  12-pts from Top
                 detailType.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0),
                 detailType.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
                 
                 // constrain detailName label
                 //  30-pts from Leading
                 //  12-pts from Bottom
                 detailName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0),
                 detailName.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),

                 // constrain detailHeart image
                 //  12-pts from Trailing
                 //  12-pts from Bottom
                 //  width: 24 height: equal to width (1:1 square)
                 detailHeart.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
                 detailHeart.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12),
                 detailHeart.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
                 detailHeart.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailHeart.widthAnchor)
        ])
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    

}
```

and this 2 lines is what i add to my Detail view controller in `viewDidLoad`

```
let v = DetailViewTableCell()
             
        detailTableView.tableHeaderView = v
```

Also i add this function

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
           super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
           
           // this is needed to allow the header view's content
           //  to determine its height
           guard let headerView = detailTableView.tableHeaderView else {
               return
           }
           
           let size = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
           
           if headerView.frame.size.height != size.height {
               headerView.frame.size.height = size.height
               detailTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
               detailTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
           }
       }
```

then in my viewForHeaderInSection inbuilt function i add this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
           
                let headerView = UIView()
        tableView.rowHeight = 80
              
              headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
              headerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
              headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
              
              
  
              
              detailMain.detailMainImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
              detailMain.detailMainImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive  = true
              detailMain.detailMainImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
              detailMain.detailMainImage.image = UIImage(named: restaurant.image)
              detailMain.detailMainImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
              detailMain.detailMainImage.clipsToBounds = true
              headerView.addSubview(detailMain.detailMainImage)
        
        //Add the name
   
             detailMain.detailName.text = restaurant.name
             headerView.addSubview(detailMain.detailName)
            
        
        
              return headerView
    }
```

but still same position , is there any thing i add to add or remove from my code

Comment: Add the expected output.

Comment: thanks, the label to be somewhere near the bottom of the image

Comment: @multiverse - first, if this is a table view cell, you should subclass it as such: `class DetailViewTableCell: UITableViewCell`. Then add your elements: `detailMainImage`, `detailName`, etc... to the (built-in) content view: `self.contentView.addSubview(detailName)`. Once you've added the subviews, you can use constraints such as `detailName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0).isActive = true`.

Comment: @DonMag - its the viewForHeaderInSection, which is a UIView hence i used DetailViewTableCell as UIView subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show where you ***want** the labels, but this should get you going...

In your "header view" class:

- add your elements: detailMainImage, detailName, etc...
- set their properties and constraints as desired

You can get auto-layout to use the constraints you've setup in the header view to automatically determine its height:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    // this is needed to allow the header view's content
    //  to determine its height
    guard let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView else {
        return
    }
    
    let size = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
    
    if headerView.frame.size.height != size.height {
        headerView.frame.size.height = size.height
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

So, here's a complete example:

```
class TestHeaderTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // instantiate the header view
        let v = DetailTableHeaderView()
        // set it as the tableHeaderView
        tableView.tableHeaderView = v
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // this is needed to allow the header view's content
        //  to determine its height
        guard let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView else {
            return
        }
        
        let size = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
        
        if headerView.frame.size.height != size.height {
            headerView.frame.size.height = size.height
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
            tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
}

class DetailTableHeaderView: UIView {
    
    var detailMainImage: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var detailName: UILabel = UILabel()
    var detailType: UILabel = UILabel()
    var detailHeart: UIImageView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        backgroundColor = .white
        
        // give the heart image view a background color so we can see its frame
        detailHeart.backgroundColor = .red
        
        if let img = UIImage(named: "teacup") {
            detailMainImage.image = img
        }
        
        // give labels some text so we can see them
        detailType.text = "Detail Type"
        detailName.text = "Detail Name"
        
        // setup fonts for labels as desired
        //detailName.font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 30)
        // I don't have "Rubik" so this is with the system font
        detailName.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
        detailName.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        detailName.textColor = UIColor.black
        
        detailType.textColor = .white
        
        [detailMainImage, detailName, detailType, detailHeart].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview($0)
        }
        
        // give main image a height
        //  set its Priority to 999 to prevent layout constraint conflict warnings
        let mainImageHeightAnchor = detailMainImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0)
        mainImageHeightAnchor.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain main image to all 4 sides
            detailMainImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            detailMainImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            detailMainImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            detailMainImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            
            // activate the height contraint
            mainImageHeightAnchor,
            
            // constrain detailType label
            //  30-pts from Leading
            //  12-pts from Top
            detailType.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0),
            detailType.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            
            // constrain detailName label
            //  30-pts from Leading
            //  12-pts from Bottom
            detailName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0),
            detailName.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),

            // constrain detailHeart image
            //  12-pts from Trailing
            //  12-pts from Bottom
            //  width: 24 height: equal to width (1:1 square)
            detailHeart.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            detailHeart.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12),
            detailHeart.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            detailHeart.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailHeart.widthAnchor),
            
        ])
    }

}
```

For this example, I just set the background color of the "heart" image view to red, and I clipped the teacup out of your image:

[image]

And this is the result:

[image]

---

**Edit** - to use the custom view as a `Section` header view...

Use the same `DetailTableHeaderView` class from above, but change the table view controller as follows:

```
class TestSectionHeaderTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 300
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 0 {
            let v = DetailTableHeaderView()

            // for example implementation...
            if let img = UIImage(named: "teacup") {
                v.detailMainImage.image = img
            }
            v.detailName.text = "Testing the Name"

            // for your implementation... 

            //if let img = UIImage(named: restaurant.image) {
            //  v.detailMainImage.image = img
            //}

            //v.detailName.text = restaurant.name

            return v
        }
        return nil;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I thought the question was about table header view. Edited my answer to reflect `Section` header view.

Comment: What is baffling is that the below code works-
 detailMain.detailName.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        detailMain.detailName.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

while this does not 

 detailMain.detailName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
                            detailMain.detailName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

No error and no change in position, why such difference ?

Comment: @multiverse - what is `detailMain`? The code you've posted doesn't show it. If you use my edited answer, you don't need to ***add any subviews*** or ***set any constraints*** in `viewForHeaderInSection`. Do all of the setup - image views and labels - in `DetailTableHeaderView` and you only need to set their properties (set the image, set the labels' text) in `viewForHeaderInSection`.